# Webpack - errors at compile ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Trying to compile files ReactJS in Webpack , but he does not see the individual modules. Please advice. In Annex I throw a screen with debbuga , while below code.

**webpackjs**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname,"build"),filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    entry: ['./src/App.jsx'],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['','.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015']
          }
         },
      ]
    }
};
```

**App.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, Redirect} from 'react-router';
import DefaultLayout from './layouts/Default';
import HomePage from './components/Home';
import PrivacyPage from './components/Privacy';

export const routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={DefaultLayout}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
        <Route path='privacy' component={PrivacyPage} />
        <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
)
```

[image: webpack errors]

Comment: This might be a freak issue with trailing commas. If you are 100% sure your folder structure is correct, try removing the trailing comma inside `loaders`. Also check package.json for trailing commas. It shouldn't cause an error like this, but sometimes computers are weird. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying it can not find the src/components folder. Check you file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install babel-loader

```
npm install babel-loader
```

and use

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
```

You may also need to create a babelrc rather than write your presets in your webpack config file and in it

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```